# Unable to locate html tag for scraping

Tags: html, python-2.7

I'm not great in HTML, so am a bit stumbled for this.

I'm trying to scrape instagram datetime posts using python, and realised that the datetime information isn't without the html document of the post. However, I am able to query it using inspect element. See below screen shot.

[image: Inspect element of date (below follow button]

Where is this datetime information located exactly, and how can I obtain it?

The example I took from is this random post "https://www.instagram.com/p/BEtMWWbjoPh/". Element is at the "12h" displayed in the page.

**[Update]** I am using urllib to grab the url, and bs4 in python to scrape. The output did not return anything with datetime. The code is below. I also printed out the entire html and I was surprised that it does not contain datetime in it.

```
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.select('time')
    for tag in tags:
        dateT = tag.get('datetime').getText()
        print dateT
```

Comment: What python library are you using the scrape the page?

Comment: Have updated my post. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem that you are experiencing is that `urllib.urlopen(url).read()` does not execute any javascript that is on the page.

Because Instagram is a client side javascript app that uses your browser to render their site, you'll need some sort of browser client to evaluate the javascript and then find the element on the page. For this, I usually use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) (I usually use it with the ruby driver `Capybara`, but I would assume that there is a python package that would work similarly)

HOWEVER, if you execute `urllib.urlopen(url).read()`, you should see a block of JSON in a script tag that begins with `<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {...`

That block of JSON will include the data you are looking for. If you were to evaluate that JSON, and parse it, you should be able access the time data you are looking for.

<s>That being said, the ***better*** way to do this is to use [instagram's api](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) to do the the crawling. They make all of this data available to developers, so you don't have to crawl an ever-changing webpage.</s>

(Apparently Instagram's API will only return public data for users who have explicitly given your app permission)

Comment: Thanks Neil, this just what I suspect too... btw just one more question b4 I click ur correct answer. I thought the Instagram has already prevented people from using their full API and downgraded normal/personal users to their sandbox API. I don't think the sandbox API can extract information aside from from their own postings. Am I right?

Comment: I just looked into it, and you are entirely correct. Sorry about that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Neil, your reply did help me anyway. From a little research, PhatomJS supports the parsing of JS in python. Thanks!

Comment: @Jake I am sorta working on something sorta related to this. Message me on twitter if you'd like. {username: BananaNeil}

Answer (score 3):

In your developer console, type this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].getAttribute('datetime');
```

This will return the data you are looking for. The above code is simply looking through the HTML for the tag name `time`, of which there is only one, then grabbing the `datetime` property from it.

As for python, check out `BeautifulSoup` if you haven't already. This library will allow you to do a similar thing in python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
soup.time['datetime']
```

Where `html_doc` is your raw HTML. To obtain the raw HTML, use the `requests` library.

Comment: Thanks chris, in developer console, I can get the datetime. For the python code, I did similarly to what you recommended, except that I use urlib to grab the html. Result is a null. I printed out the entire html for the page but it does not contain the datetime value.